# Replace JavaScript Confirm with Foundation-5 reveal modal

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, zurb-foundation, confirm

I currently use javascript confirm function to confirm form submissions. How can I replace the JavaScript confirm with a foundation-5 reveal modal?

Comment: Hi, could you explain it in detail? as far as I know, here is the link for modal implementation:  http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/reveal.html

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [this project](https://github.com/agoragames/confirm-with-reveal/blob/master/README.md). They use foundation for confirmation. On the [example page](http://blog.agoragames.com/confirm-with-reveal/), they even have different types of confirmation.

Answer (score 2):

This is super late, but here is the solution that I arrive at recently for confirm and alert dialogs (For form submissions, I'd intercept the submit button click, do nothing int he noCallback function, and submit the form in the yesCallback function):

```
function confirmWithFoundation(options, yesCallback, noCallback) {
    options.message = typeof options.message !== 'undefined' ?  options.message : 'Are you sure?';
    options.uniqueIdentifier = typeof options.uniqueIdentifier !== 'undefined' ?  options.uniqueIdentifier : options.message;
    options.yesText = typeof options.yesText !== 'undefined' ?  options.yesText : 'OK';
    options.noText = typeof options.noText !== 'undefined' ?  options.noText : '[CANCEL]';

    var uniqueIdentifier = md5(options.uniqueIdentifier);

    // return out of function if this modal already exists
    // if ($('#' + uniqueIdentifier)) { return };

    var topRow = document.createElement('div');
    topRow.classList.add('row', 'border-bottom');
    var confirmTextContainer = document.createElement('div');
    confirmTextContainer.classList.add('large-12', 'columns');
    var confirmText = document.createElement('h4');
    confirmText.innerHTML = options.message;
    confirmTextContainer.appendChild(confirmText);
    topRow.appendChild(confirmTextContainer);

    var bottomRow = document.createElement('div');
    bottomRow.classList.add('row');
    var buttonContainer = document.createElement('div');
    buttonContainer.classList.add('large-12', 'columns');
    var cancelButton = document.createElement('a');
    cancelButton.classList.add('right', 'text-button-input');
    cancelButton.innerHTML = options.noText;
    var okButton = document.createElement('button');
    okButton.classList.add('right', 'button');
    okButton.innerHTML = options.yesText;
    buttonContainer.appendChild(okButton);
    buttonContainer.appendChild(cancelButton);
    bottomRow.appendChild(buttonContainer);

    var modal = document.createElement('div');
    modal.id = uniqueIdentifier;
    modal.classList.add('reveal-modal', 'confirm-modal', 'small', 'no-padding');
    modal.dataset.reveal = '';
    modal.appendChild(topRow);
    modal.appendChild(bottomRow);

    document.body.appendChild(modal);
    $(modal).foundation('reveal', 'open');

    okButton.onclick = function() {
        yesCallback();
        $(modal).foundation('reveal', 'close');
    };

    cancelButton.onclick = function() {
        noCallback();
        $(modal).foundation('reveal', 'close');
    };
}

function alertWithFoundation(options) {
    options.message = typeof options.message !== 'undefined' ?  options.message : 'Are you sure?';
    options.uniqueIdentifier = typeof options.uniqueIdentifier !== 'undefined' ?  options.uniqueIdentifier : options.message;
    options.yesText = typeof options.yesText !== 'undefined' ?  options.yesText : 'OK';

    var uniqueIdentifier = md5(options.uniqueIdentifier);

    // return out of function if this modal already exists
    // if ($('#' + uniqueIdentifier)) { return };

    var topRow = document.createElement('div');
    topRow.classList.add('row', 'border-bottom');
    var confirmTextContainer = document.createElement('div');
    confirmTextContainer.classList.add('large-12', 'columns');
    var confirmText = document.createElement('h4');
    confirmText.innerHTML = options.message;
    confirmTextContainer.appendChild(confirmText);
    topRow.appendChild(confirmTextContainer);

    var bottomRow = document.createElement('div');
    bottomRow.classList.add('row');
    var buttonContainer = document.createElement('div');
    buttonContainer.classList.add('large-12', 'columns');
    var okButton = document.createElement('button');
    okButton.classList.add('right', 'button');
    okButton.innerHTML = options.yesText;
    buttonContainer.appendChild(okButton);
    bottomRow.appendChild(buttonContainer);

    var modal = document.createElement('div');
    modal.id = uniqueIdentifier;
    modal.classList.add('reveal-modal', 'alert-modal', 'small', 'no-padding');
    modal.dataset.reveal = '';
    modal.appendChild(topRow);
    modal.appendChild(bottomRow);

    document.body.appendChild(modal);
    $(modal).foundation('reveal', 'open');

    okButton.onclick = function() {
        $(modal).foundation('reveal', 'close');
        return false;
    };
}
```

Comment: I really like this script. Works perfect!